# How to fix "psycopg2.errors.InvalidDatetimeFormat: invalid input syntax for type date:"-"

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I have one excel file with different columns and rows that type of columns is various same as date.

some lists has exported from xlsx file with pandas and then zip those lists to one list named result.
Now I want to insert that result list on PostgreSQL,but when the value of date cell is null and also 
in my modles.py I have set datefiled to null = True,Blank= True but I got this error:

> psycopg2.errors.InvalidDatetimeFormat: invalid input syntax for type date: "-"

I'm new in coding.

```py
cursor = connection.cursor()
for z in result:
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO 
forecast_forcast(document_number,document_name,project,discipline_code,first_Plan_issue_Date,second_Plan_issue_Date,final_Plan_issue_Date,class_num,rev,latest_status,comment_status,current_complete,responsible,weight) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",z)

    connection.commit()
```

Comment: A dash (`-`) doesn't represent a null value. Replace all of those with empty values.

Comment: now I have below error:psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch: column "first_plan_issue_date" is of type date but expression is of type double precision

Comment: It's exactly what error shows, you should define that `first_Plan_issue_Date` to be of DATE data type, and you've set it to NUMERIC or such. How did you create your database, in which framework you have got that models.py/modles.py? Is that Django?

Comment: model is python and has been set to datefiled to null = True,Blank= True, in Pycharm,yes django

Answer (score 0):

please use str(datetime.datetime.now().date()) as parameter for null or blank value.